# Typescript date sending with ajax post

Tags: javascript, ajax, datetime, typescript

I develop a MVC web application in c# and I use Typescript to frontend.
I have a method into controller that receive a HttpPost request with a data model, this data model it is  aumatically generate with typelite into typescript class.

In my request data model have a datetime fields, when I send a request to backend the datatime fields are serialized to string with this format: "Sun+Dec+25+2016+11:29:33+GMT+0100+(ora+solare+Europa+occidentale)"
I like that this fileds are serilize into UTC datetime string.

My typescript code  to send request is:

```
$.ajax({
        method: callingMethod,
        url: urlToCall,
        data: *dataValue,
        beforeSend: function () {
            self.BeforeAsyncAction();
        },
    })
    .done(callbackDone)
    .fail(callbackFail)
    .always(self.CompleteAsyncAction);
}
```

dataValue is a class with this interface:

```
export class FileServiceModel extends Gedoc.WebApplication.ServiceModels.BaseServiceModel {
    Allegato: Gedoc.WebApplication.ServiceModels.FileStreamServiceModel;
    Attributi: Gedoc.WebApplication.ServiceModels.AttributoServiceModel[];
    Descrizione: string;
    DimensioneByte: number;
    *DtIn: Date;
    *DtRegistrazione: Date;
    *DtUp: Date;
    Id: number;
    Tags: string;
    Titolo: string;
}
```

- fields that i must serialize to UTC datetime.

How the best way to serialize this fields automatically

Thanks regards

Answer (score 0):

The javascript `Date` object has a [toUTCString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) method, so:

```
let d = new Date();
console.log(d); // Sun Dec 25 2016 13:36:02 GMT+0200 (IST)
console.log(d.toUTCString()); // Sun, 25 Dec 2016 11:36:02 GMT
```

In your case you can do something like:

```
function normalizeDate(data: FileServiceModel) {
    let copy = Object.assign({}, data);
    copy.DtIn = data.DtIn.toUTCString();
    copy.DtRegistrazione = data.DtRegistrazione.toUTCString();
    copy.DtUp = data.DtUp.toUTCString();

    return copy;
}

$.ajax({
        method: callingMethod,
        url: urlToCall,
        data: normalizeDate(dataValue),
        beforeSend: function () {
            self.BeforeAsyncAction();
        },
    })
        .done(callbackDone)
        .fail(callbackFail)
        .always(self.CompleteAsyncAction);
}
```